# C# WCF service get client service

Tags: c#

I have a WCF service that I have added as a reference. I change the address of the service so that it does not appear in the configuration, I try to make a shortcut so that I do not write the same things every time. What would you recommend on this?

```
internal class TestService
{
    public static TestServisClient GetServiceClient
    {
        get
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var endpoind = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:64733/TestService.svc?wsdl");
            return new TestServisClient(binding, endpoind);
        }
    }
}

testservice.getserviceclient.getdatatables();
```

Is it right to use it this way, should I call it again to close the service?

Comment: This isn't great, you don't want to have a static instance of an object like this, you probably want to set up dependency injection and have it injected into classes that need it. Also, if you have the choice, I'd avoid WCF like the plague, and just make a REST API

Comment: I was undecided between wcf and rest api, I opened a topic about it, but for now I need to continue with wcf. If you don't mind, can you give an example of the path I should follow because I don't want to repeat the same codes every time.

Comment: @tete you just accepted a very bad answer with critical errors. Why? The first snippet doesn't work *at all*. The second can easily throw when disposing. And using a property instead of a method is a recipe for disaster. Properties aren't just getter methods

Comment: @tete to make things a lot worse, establishing a connection and authenticating takes time, which means using that bad code will result in delays on every call. WCF clients are meant to be long-lived, to avoid just such delays

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I don't know what to do, if it is full of critical errors as you say, what is the correct method, can you please give an example?

Comment: I've been searching for days but couldn't find a solution. If you don't have time to write any code examples, is there a web address that clarifies the issue?

Comment: What kind of application are you building? Desktop, web? .NET Framework, .NET Core? In .NET Framework you could change the URL in the configuration file instead of passing a hard-coded URL to the proxy. Does the service use sessions? In that case you need to keep the client around for as long as the session lasts. In desktop applications you can use a singleton instance until the session completes or the application terminates.

Comment: A good reference are [the docs themselves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/clients). The [Handling Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/accessing-services-using-a-client#handling-exceptions) section in `Accessing Services using a Client` shows how to properly close a client. Generally, a client is thread-safe and since .NET Framework 4.5 proxies have async methods. In a desktop application you could reuse the same client

Comment: The configuration settings are described in the [WCF Client Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/client-configuration) page. Every client has a constructor that accepts an endpoint name that's used to look up settings in the app.config file. You can have multiple endpoints and pass the name you want each time to create a client that connects to a different URL or uses different settings.

Comment: I'm making a windows form application, I'm doing database operations on the remote server with the wcf service, for this I added the service as a reference to my project. I want to change it manually because the service connection url address is certain in the config file

Comment: As I mentioned above, instead of entering the url address every time I call the service, I want to do this in a simpler way, thank you for your advice, I've looked at these sites before, I'm reviewing them again, thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

i think i have to do it this way

```
using (TestServisClient client = new TestServisClient(
         new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(url))) 
{ ... }
```